# Copy table structure and all index except one - postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I my rails application, I am creating a clone table and while creating the clone table I want to copy the structure and all the indexes from the base table except just one.

I am currently doing it like this

1) Create a migration with

```
 def up
    execute("CREATE TABLE deleted_users (LIKE users INCLUDING INDEXES)")
 end
```

2) And another migration for deleting the index like this

```
  def up
    remove_index :deleted_users, name: :deleted_users_email_idx
  end
```

Is there a better way to copy the indexes while creating the clone table itself, for example something like

```
CREATE TABLE deleted_users (LIKE users ALL INDEXES EXCLUDING (deleted_users_email_idx))
```